# Character encoding not consistent (Win32 API)

Tags: c++, winapi

I am developing a Win32 desktop application with C++ where the target-language is Swedish. As a result of that I rely on Unicode to properly format and display any given string. However, I encountered a very peculiar issue where strings consisting of non-english characters (such as å, ä, ö) work in one part of the code, but breaks in another part of the code.

More specifically, the code works in one file, but not the other. If I move the code-block to the other file, then the text is properly displayed again. See the following example:

```
CreateWindowW(L"Button", L"Lägg till kund", WS_TABSTOP | WS_VISIBLE | WS_CHILD, 
              0, 0, 80, 25, windowHandle, (HMENU)0, NULL, NULL);
```

-Which is called from the Application.cpp file.

```
AppendMenu(m_MainMenuBar, MF_POPUP, (UINT_PTR)m_ArkivMenu, L"&Arkiv");
AppendMenu(m_MainMenuBar, MF_POPUP, (UINT_PTR)m_VisaMenu, L"&Visa");
AppendMenu(m_MainMenuBar, MF_POPUP, (UINT_PTR)m_ArkivMenu, L"&Hjälp");
AppendMenu(m_MainMenuBar, MF_POPUP, (UINT_PTR)m_ArkivMenu, L"&Sök");
```

-Which is called from the Window.cpp file.

All of this results in the following:

[image: Calling code from different headers]

Note that the code called from Window.cpp generates text with invalid characters, which indicates that the symbol(s) couldn't be found. This is very strange since the problem ceases to exist if I move the code from Window.cpp to Application.cpp.

Thus, the only logical conclusion is that the character encoding must differ between these two files, but why?

Comment: Maybe you can find an answer here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22893226/swedish-characters-dont-compare-correctly

Comment: Difficult to say *why* it's different. It's caused by the way you created and/or you saved the files.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is indeed, as the title states, "Character encoding not consistent".

And to be precise, that's the character encoding of `Window.cpp` compared to the character encoding of `Application.cpp`. I suspect the environment is Visual Studio, which can handle files in multiple encodings. But for source code that contains Unicode, you probably want to use UTF-8 with "signature" (BOM).

This is available in Visual Studio 2017+ via "Save As", and in that save dialog choose ["Save With Encoding"](https://stackoverflow.com/a/53259212/15416) instead of plain "Save".

Comment: Thank you! It turns out that one of the files, more specifically Application.h used a western european DOS signature. I have no clue as to why this occured in the first place but the problem is now fixed.